# Masonry images overlapping issue with rails 3 + turbolinks + Mozilla

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-masonry, turbolinks

I have a new and slim website with [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) and rails 3 and [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks).

The website is working fine with all browsers except with mozilla firefox.

The images are overlapping/superimposed on mozilla firefox, but on other browsers the website is working fine.

On google chrome is working fine with turbolinks.

**How can I fix this problem with mozilla firefox?**

Comment: Are you waiting until JS says all the images have loaded before firing off the masonry call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you, after several hours I was able to solve the problem with a new code for masonry because with `$('#page').masonry('reload');`

I get on console:

```
cannot call methods on masonry prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'reload'
```

So, the final that is working for me is a new masonry code with:

```
$(document).on('page:load', function(){
   $('#page').waitForImages(function(){
    finished: function() {
      var $container;
      $container = $("#page");
      $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
       return $container.masonry({
       .
       .
       //options here
       });
     });
   }, 
   waitForAll: true
 });
});
```

You can download minified waitForImages plugin for here:

https://raw.github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages/master/dist/jquery.waitforimages.min.js

This is waitForImages page:

https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages